# Unity - Game of connecting water pipes. Problem with checking if the pipes objects are connected to the central source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I`m trying to make a puzzle game where the player is presented with a grid of pipes with one water source. The player has to rotate the pipes in order to connect them all to each other and, of course, to the water source.

The problem I`m stuck with is this:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

As shown in the pictures, when I rotate a pipe that is connected to a group of other pipes, the connection to the water isn`t broken in the remaining group, it only works in a single adjacent pipe.

This is happening because of the way I`m doing the connections using a group of colliders in each exit of the pipes, as shown in the pictures below.

Colliders - Scene:

[image]

Colliders - Hierarchy:

[image]

If the collided object is connected to water (by a bool), it adds the collided object to a list. If the list is greater than 0, activates the blue sprite. If the list is empty, deactivates the blue sprite. As shown in the code sample below.

Triggers that check if the object is connected to water:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.GetComponent<FlipPipes2>() != null) {
        isFlowingWater = other.GetComponent<FlipPipes2>().flowingWater;
    }
    if (other.CompareTag("WaterPipe")) {
        if (other.name == "Filled_Cross" || isFlowingWater) {
            myFlipPipes.flowingWater = true;
        }
        TestingScoreStatic.connectedPipes++;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (!inList) {
        myFlipPipes.collidedObjectsList.Add(other.gameObject);
        inList = true;
    }
    if (other.name == "Filled_Cross" || isFlowingWater) {
        myFlipPipes.flowingWater = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("WaterPipe")) {
        myFlipPipes.collidedObjectsList.Remove(other.gameObject);
        myFlipPipes.flowingWater = false;
        isConnectedToWater = false;
        TestingScoreStatic.connectedPipes--;
        inList = false;
    }
}
```

Code sample of the actual change of sprite:

```
private void Update() {
    if (collidedObjectsList.Count > 0) {
        filledPipe.SetActive(true);
    } else {
        filledPipe.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Even if the tile connected to the source of water loses its connection, the others don't, because they are still connected to water tiles.

**How can I check if there is a valid path to the source of water? Or any other way to do what I need?**

Here are some other code samples that may help:

The method that creates the board:

```
private void SetUp() {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
            int tempIndex = levelManager.levelOne[pipeIndex];
            GameObject pipe = Instantiate(pipes[tempIndex], tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            pipe.transform.parent = transform;
            allPipes[i, j] = pipe;
            if (!pipe.CompareTag("WaterPipe")) {
                shuffleSpawnedPipes.pipes.Add(pipe);
            }
            pipeIndex++;
        }
    }
    shuffleSpawnedPipes.ShufflePipes();
}
```

(Terrible) Attempt to check every pipe with a double `for` loop:

```
void IsConnectedToWater() {
    if (column > 0 && column < board.width - 1) {
        GameObject leftPipe1 = board.allPipes[column - 1, row];
        GameObject rightPipe1 = board.allPipes[column + 1, row];
        if (leftPipe1.tag == this.gameObject.tag && rightPipe1.tag == this.gameObject.tag) {
            leftPipe1.GetComponent<Pipe>().connectedToWater = true;
            rightPipe1.GetComponent<Pipe>().connectedToWater = true;
            connectedToWater = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this does not work because it is not checking if the current object is colliding. Even with the collision check, the resuls is the same. I'm in a loop of doing many different attempts resulting in the same thing.

Comment: "Is something possible?" Is not a useful question, it could be answered with just a plain "yes", totally valid but useless. Consider adding some code with an actual attempt to solve the problem and a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @bradbury9, i`ll improve the post and rephrase the question.

Comment: The problem I see here is that you only check for the object that is rotated and the one connected to it. But the other pipes that were connected but are not anymore without being rotated don't get updated. I would personally separate the data of the water flowing and the collision. Hence you can have a algorithm that check which object is connected to water and which one are not more easily, and then update the views. 
Also when you rotate an object you have multiple collisions exiting, the first one arriving change the state of the object, that can be a problem for the other pipe connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a pathfinding algorithm.

Create a recursive function that will check paths to your watersource. Instead of checking each element if it is connected to water check if your watersource object is in a list of connected objects of that checked pipe. If its not save that pipe object into list of `checkedObjects` and go to next connected object, repeat till you checked all pipe objects connected to each other. If none of the objects had your watersource in the list of connected objects it means all the objects in `checkedObjects` path are not connected to water and you can disable the water sprite on all of them.